# How to read a file in CLion in c programming

Tags: c, clion

I recently switched from Code Blocks to CLion and im having trouble understanding why i cant read a file.

In code block i would just open a file usually named it `file.txt` then read it using `fopen("file.txt","r")`

Apparently this isnt working in CLion cuz it keeps printing out the error message you put when you check if the file is opened or not

Does anyone know a step by step guide on how to Read files in Clion?

Comment: Odds are your working directory is not where you think it is. Does it fail if you use an absolute path to the file? Does it fail if you run the program from the command line in the same directory where the file is?

Comment: @RetiredNinja im just using the same method. Not too sure what absolute path to the file is. I just right click where it says main.c then new and file

Comment: @RetiredNinja  if youre talking about where the file im trying to read is its in the same folder as the main.c

Comment: An absolute path is the full path to the file like `c:/stuff/file.txt` or `/stuff/file.txt` depending on what operating system you are using. When you run the program from inside CLion it will set the working directory to somewhere that may not be where your code is. It may be configurable in the options somewhere. One way to figure out where would be to create a file and then go search for it.

Comment: @SeverjanLici  Being in the same folder as the source code is the problem - it probably needs to be in the same folder as the executable - but when you rebuild that directory might be deleted so using an absolute path would fix it properly.

Comment: An IDE has no control over what you can/can't do in C (or any other language). An IDE is a tool - that is supposed to make working with a language easier. For small/learning programs, IDE's generally complicate the process 10-fold requiring you learn an IDE (and how to configure it) just to compile "Hello world". It is far easier to simply learn to build from the command line (and 10x faster too). You have an IDE configuration problem, not a C problem. As others suggest, the configuration for where your file is located is off. Using the command line, that is never an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your run/debug configuration and change the working directory to where the file is.

Comment: I don't recommend this. I would rather recommend putting the file where the working directory is. I am not familiar with CLion, but the project's directory structure is probably meaningful, so it would not be meaningful to change it, unless you know what you are doing. Separating the project's source files from its input/output files is probably generally a good idea.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).